# asp.net multi-line textbox strange behavior on postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autopostback

I have a .NET 4.0 web app, code-behind in vb.net, with a Master page/Content page architecture. An updatepanel exists in the Site.Master which this contentplaceholder exists. In one of the content pages, I have a Formview and in the InsertItemTemplate, there are multiple multi-line textboxes. I am seeing an issue  when there's text in any of the mutli-line textboxes and a postback occurs due to a dropdownlist selection change, the page freezes up, i.e., the postback times out the page. I have spent lots of time determining troubleshooting this behavior and if I change the textmode of the textboxes to single line(default), this behavior is not witnessed.

My question is: Has anyone experienced this or is there something that I have not thought of to investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

It can be hard to debug code inside of an `UpdatePanel`. Your best bet is to comment out the `UpdatePanel` and see where the error is at, because it may be hiding it.

You can also check the JavaScript console for vague error messages, but those aren't terribly useful usually.